# Concatenate Object values with javascript

Tags: javascript

```
const person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};
```

Im trying to concatenate firstName and lastName to get another object.

```
const person = {Name:"John Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};
```

How can i do that in javascript

Comment: `person.firstName + " " + person.lastName`

Comment: Why do you think concatenation is different with object properties than anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to get name

Why should we use `getter`? You can imagine this situation, if you assign `Name` property, as usual, it will generate `setter` and `getter` on that, but seemingly, you're expecting to get value only.

You can check the problem I mentioned with `getter` and `setter` below (the code snippet is hidden)

```js
let person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyeColor: "blue"
};

person = {
  ...person,
  Name: person.firstName + " " + person.lastName
};


console.log(person.Name) // John Doe
person.Name = "new name" //assign a new value
console.log(person.Name) //it becomes `new name`!
```

Here is how we use `getter` instead of assigning values

```js
const person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyeColor: "blue",
  get Name() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
  }
};


console.log(person.Name); //John Doe
person.Name = "new name"; //try to assign a new name
console.log(person.Name); //it's still `John Doe`!
```

You also can add another function as a class to initialize `Name` property without modifying the original object (`person`)

```js
const person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyeColor: "blue"
};

function PersonWithFullName(data) {
  return {
    ...data,
    get Name() {
      return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
    }
  }
}

const updatedPerson = new PersonWithFullName(person)

console.log({ person })
console.log({ updatedPerson })
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};
const { firstName, lastName, ...restOfPerson } = person;
const newPerson = { Name: `${firstName} ${lastName}`, ...restOfPerson };
console.log(newPerson);
```

I think you are looking for this, you can destructure the object and get the firstName and lastName and use object literal or concatenation to create your Name value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a person factory class:

```js
const p1 = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  age: 50,
  eyeColor: 'blue',
};

class Person {
  constructor(person) {
    this.name = `${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}`;
    this.age = person.age;
    this.eyeColor = person.eyeColor;
  }
}

const person = new Person(p1);
console.log(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function personWithName(person) {
    person['Name'] = [person.firstName, person.lastName].join(" ");
    delete person.firstName;
    delete person.lastName;
    return person;
}
```

you can use it as

```
person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};
person = personWithName(person);
```